Send a direct message with google chat api to a user inside my (Google Workspace) organization with only e-mail
We are trying to send an asynchronous direct message (DM) to a user within our organization (managed with Google Workspace) with the google chat API. We have the users validate email, but not his/her account ID. We are running on google app engine with a service account.
a) When using the spaces.findDirectMessage API call with name:'users/'+...The chat API does not allow an email but requires an account ID.
b) When using spaces.find(...), we find only DM spaces where the user has previously added our chat app. However, we would prefer if the users don't have to do something before getting a message.
for a), we could get the account ID with the directory API, but this would require elevated privileges (domain-wide delegation) for the service account the app is running with, and we would prefer not to have to grant these privileges.
Any suggestions on how to get this done are welcome!

You can use email directly in your api call instead of id

the user's email address can be used as an alias for {user} in API requests. For example, if the People API Person profile ID for user@example.com is 123456789, you can use users/user@example.com as an alias to reference users/123456789. Only the canonical resource name (for example users/123456789) will be returned from the API.

Source: https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/User
